# How to append dynamic values to the area chart in High charts or convert the data to arrays?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, charts, highcharts

I am fetching the data from database. After the success execution of my query the following is the result. For every `BRANCH` there are 4 values.

```
    <?php
     $data = 
    '{"8":{"SDATE":"01-APR-2013","BRANCH":"MEDICAL","FEES":"16000","PER_INC":".68","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "9":{"SDATE":"01-AUG-2012","BRANCH":"MEDICAL","FEES":"14000","PER_INC":".047","CLG_RANK":"6"},
     "10":{"SDATE":"01-DEC-2012","BRANCH":"MEDICAL","FEES":"15500","PER_INC":".87","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "11":{"SDATE":"01-FEB-2013","BRANCH":"MEDICAL","FEES":"17500","PER_INC":".72","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "12":{"SDATE":"01-JAN-2013","BRANCH":"ELECTRICAL","FEES":"12200","PER_INC":".18","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "13":{"SDATE":"01-JUL-2012","BRANCH":"ELECTRICAL","FEES":"17000","PER_INC":".071","CLG_RANK":"6"},
     "14":{"SDATE":"01-JUL-2013","BRANCH":"ELECTRICAL","FEES":"15700","PER_INC":".044","CLG_RANK":"8"},
     "15":{"SDATE":"01-JUN-2013","BRANCH":"ELECTRICAL","FEES":"13000","PER_INC":".78","CLG_RANK":"8"},
     "16":{"SDATE":"01-MAR-2013","BRANCH":"MECHANICAL","FEES":"13200","PER_INC":".95","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "17":{"SDATE":"01-MAY-2013","BRANCH":"MECHANICAL","FEES":"16000","PER_INC":".27","CLG_RANK":"8"},
     "18":{"SDATE":"01-NOV-2012","BRANCH":"MECHANICAL","FEES":"14000","PER_INC":".82","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "19":{"SDATE":"01-OCT-2012","BRANCH":"MECHANICAL","FEES":"17500","PER_INC":".32","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "20":{"SDATE":"01-SEP-2012","BRANCH":"CIVIL","FEES":"13500","PER_INC":".67","CLG_RANK":"6"},
     "21":{"SDATE":"01-APR-2013","BRANCH":"CIVIL","FEES":"14700","PER_INC":".56","CLG_RANK":"8"},
     "22":{"SDATE":"01-AUG-2012","BRANCH":"CIVIL","FEES":"18000","PER_INC":"0","CLG_RANK":"7"},
     "23":{"SDATE":"01-DEC-2012","BRANCH":"CIVIL","FEES":"15000","PER_INC":"0","CLG_RANK":"8"}}';
      ?>
```

I have to convert the data into array and pass the array values to the graph. Please look at this graph http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-stacked. The x-axis values must be `SDATE` values i.e, date. The y-axis values must be `FEES`. In the link that I posted the countries that can be seen in the graph and below x-axis are to replaced by the values of `BRANCH`.

```
    $(function () {
       var data = new Array();
       data = '<?php echo $data; ?>'; 
       // code to be written
     });
```

The summary is that in the graph that I have mentioned in the URL above are to be replaced by $data values with respect to the `BRANCH` i.e based on the branch x-axis and y-axis values are to be shown.

How can I do it. please anyone help. I have tried the whole day. But as I am not good at arrays I am unable to do this one. Atleast tell how to covert the values to arrays with respect to the `BRANCH` values

Answer (score 0):

Generally the problem is that it is not JSON / proper string. So at the beginning I recommend you to take care about your format and then structure. It should be array of series and data. Fields should be name correctly with highcharts standard, not custom names. Dates required to be timestamps. At the SO there is many similiar topics.

Article which can be useful:

- http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro